# I am creating a Chatbot using amazon Lex and amazon Lambda, I just want to know I I receive "NULL"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

the user will ask "I want to know how many modules I have"
the bot will ask for faculty and course name, when a user enters software engineering, I want to fulfill the intent, but I don’t know where is my mistake can anyone help?

```
  const intentName = event.sessionState.intent.name;
  if(intentName == "Greeting"){
    
    const userName = event.sessionState.intent.slots.user_name.value.originalValue;
  
    return{
      "sessionState":{
        "dialogAction":{
          "type": "ElicitIntent"
        }
      },
      "messages": [{
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": "Hi " + userName + ", How can I help you?"
      }],
    }
  }
  if( intentName == "Course"){
    if(event.sessionState.intent.slots.faculty_name == null){
       return{
      "sessionState":{
        "dialogAction":{
          "SlotToElicit":"course_name",
          "type": "ElicitSlot"
        },
      "intent":{
        "name": "Course",
        "state": "Inprogress"
      }
      }
    };
    }
    if(event.sessionState.intent.slots.Course_name.value.originalValue == "software engineering"){
        return{
      "sessionState":{
        "dialogAction":{
          "type": "Cose"
        },
      "intent":{
        "name": "Course",
        "state": "fulfilled "
      }
      }
    };
    }
  }
 
};
```

Comment: Hi there. What error message are you getting? Can you elaborate on what's happening and what you're expecting?

Comment: well basically, I want when the user enter course name which is software engineering, to fulfill the intent but it does not show the fulfillment message it just says intent is fulfilled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure each intent to use the Lambda function for fulfillment.

It looks like you're using Lex V2 so to do this you would need to expand the *Fulfillment* tab in your `Course` intent, click on the *Advanced options* button and then ensure the *Use a Lambda function for fulfillment* box is checked.

Doing so will direct Lex to invoke the Lambda function whenever all required slots have been assigned valid values and the intent is ready for fulfillment.

Your function will need to respond with a payload similar to this:

```
{
   'sessionState': {
       'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
       'dialogAction': {
             'type': 'Close'
       },
       'intent': intent_request['sessionState']['intent']
   },
   'messages': {
       'contentType': 'PlainText',
       'content': 'Fulfilled by Lambda function'
   },
   'sessionId': intent_request['sessionId'],
   'requestAttributes': intent_request['requestAttributes'] 
}
```

Note that the fulfillment message that's displayed to the user is passed to Lex by the Lambda function. Read more about the Lambda response format [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-response-format).

Be sure to check out the [AWS Lex Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/what-is.html) for more in-depth information.